# wxpython move drawn point with mouse

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am using wxpython to do some image processing job now. I want to draw a point with mouse left button down and move the drawn point with mouse move.

The following is my code. It is ok when draw point with left button down, but when I move the mouse the previous drawn points also display which did not meet my expectation.

How to hide the previous point when I move the mouse so that it looks like I am move the points?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    isLeftDown = False

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, size=wx.Size(500, 500))
        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, 
                                wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        bSizer1.Add(self.m_panel, 3, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(500, 500)
        self.staticBMP = wx.StaticBitmap(self.m_panel, wx.ID_ANY, bmp)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer1)

        # bind event
        self.staticBMP.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.staticBMP.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnLeftUp)
        self.staticBMP.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMove)

    def OnLeftDown(self, event):
        pos = event.GetPositionTuple()
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self.staticBMP)
        dc.DrawCircle(pos[0], pos[1], 5)
        self.isLeftDown = True

    def OnLeftUp(self, event):
        self.isLeftDown = False

    def OnMove(self, event):
        if self.isLeftDown:
            pos = event.GetPositionTuple()
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self.staticBMP)
            dc.DrawCircle(pos[0], pos[1], 3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to draw a new circle, but move the existing one by updating a list of parameters.

```
import wx

WHITE_COLOR = (255,255,255)

class MoveCircle():

    def __init__(self, parent): 
        self.parent=parent
        self.parameters = [36,36,30]
        self.advance=3
        self.parent.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.on_paint)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self.parent)
        self.parent.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.on_timer, self.timer)
        self.timer.Start(100)

    def on_paint(self, event=None):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.parent)
        dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush("blue"))
        dc.DrawCircle(*self.parameters)

    def on_timer(self, event):
        self.parameters[0] += self.advance
        print self.parameters
        if self.parameters[0] < 36 or self.parameters[0] > 210:
            self.advance *= -1
        self.parent.Refresh()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    title = "Circle"
    frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, title, size=(250, 200))
    MoveCircle(frame)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Yes, I want to move the existing point in face. Your answer is using the timer event and draw on frame. Is that OK when I use mouse move event and draw on StaticBitmap?

Comment: For Heaven's sake. It's an example!

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this effect with a dirty method. But I do not know whether it is property method. If it is the wrong way please tell me and I will update or delete this answer. here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    isLeftDown = False

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, size=wx.Size(500, 500))
        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.m_panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        bSizer1.Add(self.m_panel, 3, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(500, 500)
        self.staticBMP = wx.StaticBitmap(self.m_panel, wx.ID_ANY, self.bmp)

        self.SetSizer(bSizer1)

        # bind event
        self.staticBMP.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnLeftDown)
        self.staticBMP.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnLeftUp)
        self.staticBMP.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMove)

    def OnLeftDown(self, event):
        pos = event.GetPositionTuple()
        dc = wx.ClientDC(self.staticBMP)
        dc.DrawCircle(pos[0], pos[1], 5)
        self.isLeftDown = True

    def OnLeftUp(self, event):
        self.isLeftDown = False

    def OnMove(self, event):
        if self.isLeftDown:
            pos = event.GetPositionTuple()
            dc = wx.ClientDC(self.staticBMP)
            dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0)
            dc.DrawCircle(pos[0], pos[1], 5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```